# Using .val following an onclick works in emulator but not on device

Tags: jquery, ios, intel-xdk

I'm working on an app at the moment which has a list view which contains a list of students. When I tap on a student, the app should present a form pre-filled with that student's information for viewing or editing. It works fine in the emulator, but when I test it on my device (iPad), tapping the name of a student just presents a blank form with none of the information populated.

**This is the list view:**

```
      $.each(jsonData.students, function() {
         myListContent += '<li id="'+ jsonData.students[i].id+'" style="background: #f0f0f0; border-left: solid 5px ' + jsonData.students[i].belt + ';"><a href="" onclick="checkStudent(this);">'+jsonData.students[i].firstname+' '+jsonData.students[i].lastname+ '<br>Last Seen: '+jsonData.students[i].lastseen+'</a></li>';
                   i++;
});
```

**This is the code for populating the form:**

```
  function checkStudent(el) {

   var id = $(el).closest('li').attr('id');
   $.getJSON("students.php", function(data){

       id--;
       var mystudent = JSON.stringify(data); 
       var viewjsonData = JSON.parse(mystudent);
       $('#view-firstname').val(viewjsonData.students[id].firstname);
       $('#view-surname').val(viewjsonData.students[id].lastname);
       $('#view-belt').val(viewjsonData.students[id].belt);
       $('#view-lastseen').val(viewjsonData.students[id].lastseen);
       $('#view-comments').val(viewjsonData.students[id].comments);
       $('#view-facebook').val(viewjsonData.students[id].facebook);
       $('#view-phone').val(viewjsonData.students[id].phone);
       $('#view-gender').val(viewjsonData.students[id].gender);
       $('#view-mathours').val(viewjsonData.students[id].mathours).this('refresh');

         });
       activate_subpage("#studentProfile");   

     };
```

I'm confused since it's working in the emulator. Any tips would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What emulator are you using? Are you using the ios simulator on a mac?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The Intel XDK has a built-in emulator. I've got it set to iOS mode. I'm on a Windows PC for development.

Comment: I don't think that's the same as native, so that is why you are most likely seeing different results.

Comment: Can you please update your question. There seems to be some formatting issues.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how/where I should be calling the refresh to populate the fields properly on iOS please? Sorry, I'll try to fix the formatting!

Comment: Try linking the link like so: <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="checkStudent(this);">

Comment: Thanks! I just tested that on my iPad and it's working now! What's the significance of the javascript: void(0) please?

thanks again.

Comment: Answered below. I changed it to use # instead. The issue was that your href wasn't set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that Safari is picky for links. If you don't set the href value, the links don't work. Because in this case in this case you don't need to set the link to point to any page as it's just got an onclick, set it to `#`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="checkStudent(this);">
```

Using `#` will mean that when you click on the link it won't go anywhere, but you must ensure that your onclick function also returns false to prevent the page from scrolling up to the top.

```
function checkStudent(el) {
    ...

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks! That explains a lot of other issues I'm having too.